# What does '(1)' in tab title mean?

Tags: support, design

It could be seen somtimes when I surfing Ask Ubuntu that something different on the title of my web-browser, which is '(', number, and ')' such as (2).

> '(2) Ask Ubuntu' 
>   '(1) Ask Ubuntu'

Comment: Just so you know, this is the [ubuntu.se] meta site, where we talk about [ubuntu.se]. Your rep is the same as that on the main site, and it doesn't change based on accepts / upvotes.

Comment: I guess this should have the tag [tag:support], not [tag:discussion] (I’m not allowed to edit).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is the number of new questions since you last refreshed the page.

This can be done either by reloading the page (e.g. with <kbd>F5</kbd> in FireFox) or by clicking the grey `X questions with new activity` banner above the question list. Note that the second option does only load new questions, but does *not* actualize the state (votes, views, answers...) of the already shown ones.

Comment: *or clicked the "load X new questions"